# Using node.js and coffeescript for executing Ubuntu commands

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

I am using `child_process.exec` to execute Ubuntu commands with node.js in coffeescript. When I execute the following commands:

```
list = child_process.exec("ls")
print list
```

It prints this:

```
[Object Object]
```

Why isn't a proper output of `ls` command printed? What should I do to get a proper output for commands?

Answer (score 2):

You're attempting to run an asynchronous function synchronously. The correct way to do this is:

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;

exec('ls', function (error, stdout, stderr) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Source: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback

If you really wish to execute a command synchronously, you can use execSync. However, I'd advise against that, since it blocks your node code from doing anything until the process finishes.

ExecSync: https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_execsync_command_options

Comment: It isn't working. Maybe the coffeescript is interfering with it. This is a part of the traceback:
`[Wed Jun 24 2015 17:13:40 GMT+0530 (IST)] ERROR Unable to load /home/cube26/Desktop/hubot 2.0/scripts/abuse: SyntaxError: unexpected {
  at Object.exports.throwSyntaxError (/home/cube26/Desktop/hubot 2.0/node_modules/hubot/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/helpers.js:197:13)
  at Object.parser.yy.parseError (/home/cube26/Desktop/hubot 2.0/node_modules/hubot/node_modules/coffee-script/lib/coffee-script/coffee-script.js:265:20)
`

Answer (score 0):

Found it! 
Can be accessed using ->

`print list.main.<attribute_name>`